# How to test a java test class?

Tags: java, testing

I have created a JUnit conformance java test class. It basically runs as a presubmit test whenever a developer submitting a code.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ConformanceTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // implementation, e.g. reading from a flag
    }

    @Test
    public void testStuff() {
        // chekcing implementation
    }
}
```

I would like to create a test for that class (in this case ConformanceTestTest.java).

Do I have more elegant way rather than doing something like this

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ConformanceTestTest {

    @Test
    public void testTestStuff() {
        ConformanceTest test = new ConformanceTest();
        // Setting up the environment, e.g. setting the flag for conformance
        // test class

        /* Need to understand the ConformanceTest lifecycle 
        instead of testing 'testStuff()' only */
        test.setUp(); 

        assertException(AssertionError.class, test.testStuff());

        /* I might have to do test.tearDown() if there is any */
    }
}
```

Comment: JUnit has already written that for you. No need to test that JUnit works as expected.

Comment: why do you want a "testception"

Comment: I want to test my testStuff(). 
If I am not clear enough, the ConformanceTest reads value from a flag and test whether it's correct or not. To check whether the ConformanceTest is working as I expect or not. I need to create ConformanceTestTest @JBNizet

Comment: Then write it. It's just another class. But make sure to also write a ConformanceTestTestTest to test that ConformanceTestTest is correct. And a ConformanceTestTestTestTest to test that ConformanceTestTestTest is correct :-)